# Zend Framework with Google Chart

Tags: zend-framework, google-visualization

I was looking for some nice tool to generating charts and I think `Google Charts` will be the best. But I am wondering if there are some ready to use libraries to connect `Google Charts` with `Zend Framework`.

Did you use them both common ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look at http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=google+chart&x=0&y=0&go_search=1

There's no google chart classes distributed with Zend framework itself but there are plenty of 3rd party classes out there for what you need.